# Как реализовать систему появления монстров?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Есть класс Location, в нём мы делаем конструктор

```
public Location(String _name,Integer[] _monsterPool, Integer[] _monsterPoolChance){
    locationName = _name;
    monsterPool = _monsterPool;
    monsterPoolChance = _monsterPoolChance;
}
```

где locationName - название локации,
monsterPool - массив ID монстров, встречающихся в этой локации, monsterPoolChance - массив шанса появления этих монстров. В основном классе мы создаём паттерн локации

```
locationPattern[0] = new Location("Test Location", new Integer[]{0,1,2}, new Integer[]{15,15,70});
locationPattern[1] = new Location("Test Location2", new Integer[]{0,1,2,3}, new Integer[]{30,15,15,40});
```

где new Integer[]#1 - массив с ID монстров, которые встретятся на этой локации, new Integer[]#2 - шанс появления данных монстров (по порядку). При взаимодействии с этой локацией должен появиться один из этих монстров.

Вопрос: Каким образом можно реализовать данный метод?

Где currentMonster = monsterPattern[id, случайно полученное из массива паттерна локации с шансом из массива.] Можно использовать немного другой принцип. Важно, чтобы локация содержала айди монстров и шанс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, можно так

Берём случайное число от 0 до 100, а потом в цикле бежим по всем процентам и проверяем в какой промежуток попал индекс

```
public static int getIndexForMonsterPool(Integer[] probability){
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(101);
    int percentTotal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<probability.length; ++i){
        percentTotal += probability[i];
        if(rand<percentTotal){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD: по просьбе автора**

```
public static int getIndexOfMonster(Integer[] probability, Integer[] monsterPool){
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(101);
    int percentTotal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<probability.length; ++i){
        percentTotal += probability[i];
        if(rand<percentTotal){
            return monsterPool[i];
        }
    }
    return monsterPool[0];
}
```

Comment: Не совсем корректно работает. Исправьте пожалуйста для тех, кто вдруг наткнётся. В метод лучше загружать не только probability, но и pool, потому что если 1-е ID начинается, скажем, на 50, 2-60, 3-70, то возвращённая i будет равна от 0 до 3, и появившийся монстр отобразится некорректно(id 0-3 вместо 50-70), поэтому выглядеть будет так: (Integer[] probability, integer[] monsterPool); return monsterPool[i]

Comment: ну функция то возвращает индекс для monsterPool как раз, а не индекс монстра

Comment: Если так, то да, но можно всё в 1 метод засунуть